# How can I refer to a column in a subquery in the most outer SELECT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

**Description**: I'm trying to refer to a column that is `SomeID` of a `Readings` table that consists of the root nodes in a network of `Readings` that have their `Connections` modeled with `UpstreamID`s and `DownstreamID`s.

The resulting query is giving me all the upstream `Readings` of a set of root `Readings` and aggregating/grouping by the month and year a `DailyReadings`' `SomeDate` falls into.

**What I have so far**

I have the following query:

```
-- Query values of readings upstream of AnotherIDs that match their SpecialNumber for a whole month, summing values
SELECT  
    md.SomeID AS 'Upstream SomeID',
    m.AnotherID,
    -- I'd like to refer to the root SomeID here
    CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, SomeDate) AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, SomeDate) AS VARCHAR) AS 'Month', 
    SUM(md.SomeValue) AS 'Sum of SomeValue' 
FROM 
    DailyReadings rd 
INNER JOIN 
    Readings r ON r.SomeID = rd.SomeID
WHERE 
    rd.SomeID IN 
    (
        SELECT UpstreamID 
        FROM Connections
        WHERE DownstreamID IN 
        ( 
            -- I want this column in my outer select. 
            -- I want a column for this ID (SomeID)
            SELECT SomeID 
            FROM Readings
            WHERE SpecialNumber = AnotherID
            AND SpecialNumber IN 
            (
                '227796B', '225044', '578283', '578133', '578132',
                '577925', '577878', '224998', '228282', '577394',
                '227844', '225094', '578131', '218374', '577732', 
                '227845', '224978', '227773', '578280', '578078', 
                '577930', '228220', '578121', '227389', '218206', 
                '578179', '228034', '227864', '22593', '578040',
                '578131'
            ) 
            OR SpecialNumber LIKE '%228166%' 
            OR SpecialNumber LIKE '%577968%' 
            OR SpecialNumber LIKE '%228220%' 
            OR SpecialNumber LIKE '%577394%' 
            OR SpecialNumber LIKE '%578132%'
        )
    ) 
GROUP BY 
    rd.SomeID, AnotherID, DATEPART(YEAR, SomeDate), DATEPART(MONTH, SomeDate) 
ORDER BY 
    'Month' DESC, AnotherID DESC
```

**Question**:

Can I display `SomeID` from the set of root `Readings` that began the traversal to find the upstream `Readings` for each of the rows that are in the resulting table?

Comment: aren't you already joining on readings.SomeID? So it would equal dailyreadings.SomeID?

Comment: @kbball - unfortunately that will give me the upstream `SomeID` but I already have that in the select statement. In addition, I'm interested in the `SomeID` associated with the reading downstream in the innermost query

Comment: Ok just clarifying that this is a different ID even though they are both called SomeID

Comment: Same column of same table. Just at different stages of the traversal

Comment: What is the md table sorry. I don't see the join for that one

Comment: That's a mistake. Should have been `rd`. And no worries! Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Isn't the `SELECT SomeID` going to be equal to `WHERE DownstreamID` in all cases?  It might be `IN`' but a single value.  Or did you want all of the `SomeID` for any that match?  In which case simply `JOIN` to it.  Very likely I've misunderstood here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create sub tables on the go and then join them, can be done using Cte as well but try this first. You might want to add your desired columns in select list(s) and modify the group by accordingly.

```
    SELECT  
     md.SomeID AS 'Upstream SomeID'
    ,m.AnotherID
    -- I'd like to refer to the root SomeID here
    ,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, SomeDate) AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, SomeDate) AS VARCHAR) as 'Month' 
    ,SUM(md.SomeValue) AS 'Sum of SomeValue' 
FROM DailyReadings rd 
INNER JOIN Readings r ON r.SomeID = rd.SomeID
INNER JOIN (SELECT UpstreamID 
    FROM Connections) A
On rd.someid = a.upstreamid
INNER JOIN (SELECT SomeID 
        FROM Readings
        WHERE SpecialNumber = AnotherID
        AND SpecialNumber IN  
        ( 
             '227796B' 
            ,'225044' 
            ,'578283' 
            ,'578133' 
            ,'578132' 
            ,'577925' 
            ,'577878' 
            ,'224998' 
            ,'228282' 
            ,'577394' 
            ,'227844' 
            ,'225094' 
            ,'578131' 
            ,'218374' 
            ,'577732' 
            ,'227845' 
            ,'224978' 
            ,'227773' 
            ,'578280' 
            ,'578078' 
            ,'577930' 
            ,'228220' 
            ,'578121' 
            ,'227389' 
            ,'218206' 
            ,'578179' 
            ,'228034' 
            ,'227864' 
            ,'22593' 
            ,'578040' 
            ,'578131' 
        ) 
        OR SpecialNumber LIKE '%228166%' 
        OR SpecialNumber LIKE '%577968%' 
        OR SpecialNumber LIKE '%228220%' 
        OR SpecialNumber LIKE '%577394%' 
        OR SpecialNumber LIKE '%578132%') B
On A.DownstreamId = B.SomeId
```

Comment: This isn't working for me because the `DownstreamID` from `A` is unknown by the time the query gets down to the bottom.

Comment: @JakeSmith did you try to add that column in A or just put the whole table name instead of A.

Comment: I didn't change a thing from your suggestion. The last line

Comment: ok, replace "(SELECT UpstreamID FROM Connections)" with Connections ?

Answer (score 0):

So you'll have to translate this according to your actual schema but I don't see any reason why you can't just join these tables. Note that the reading table is joined twice:

```
SELECT  
     md.SomeID AS 'Upstream SomeID'
    ,r2.SomeID
    -- I'd like to refer to the root SomeID here
    ,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, SomeDate) AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, SomeDate) AS VARCHAR) as 'Month' 
    ,SUM(rd.SomeValue) AS 'Sum of SomeValue' 
FROM DailyReadings rd 
INNER JOIN Readings r ON r.SomeID = rd.SomeID
INNER JOIN Connections c ON rd.SomeID = c.UpstreamID
INNER JOIN Readings r2 ON c.DownstreamID = r2.SomeID
WHERE r2.SpecialNumber = AnotherID
AND r2.SpecialNumber IN
        ( 
             '227796B' 
            ,'225044' 
            ,'578283' 
            ,'578133' 
            ,'578132' 
            ,'577925' 
            ,'577878' 
            ,'224998' 
            ,'228282' 
            ,'577394' 
            ,'227844' 
            ,'225094' 
            ,'578131' 
            ,'218374' 
            ,'577732' 
            ,'227845' 
            ,'224978' 
            ,'227773' 
            ,'578280' 
            ,'578078' 
            ,'577930' 
            ,'228220' 
            ,'578121' 
            ,'227389' 
            ,'218206' 
            ,'578179' 
            ,'228034' 
            ,'227864' 
            ,'22593' 
            ,'578040' 
            ,'578131' 
        ) 
        OR SpecialNumber LIKE '%228166%' 
        OR SpecialNumber LIKE '%577968%' 
        OR SpecialNumber LIKE '%228220%' 
        OR SpecialNumber LIKE '%577394%' 
        OR SpecialNumber LIKE '%578132%' 
    )
) 
GROUP BY rd.SomeID, r2.SomeID, DATEPART(YEAR, SomeDate), 
DATEPART(MONTH, SomeDate) 
ORDER BY 'Month' DESC, AnotherID DESC
```

Comment: If I take this approach, I get 2000 more records (~8,000 as opposed to 6,000) with the query from my question.  This makes me feel like this isn't quite the same.

Comment: It's hard to say why without looking at your data. It might be helpful to see a short example of tables and sample data